# How to post data to Action URL from MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC.
Actually, I've a scenario in ASP.Net where I'm `submitting data`(which contains Amount,RedirectURL etc) to a `URL`(Payment Gateway) like this :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" action="https://test2pay.ghl.com/IPGSG/Payment.aspx">
        <div>
            <%=eGHLPurchaseItems%>
            <input type="submit" value="Pay Now" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

and it will `redirect to that payment gateway page` and after successful transaction, I will be `redirected back to my application` page with some `extra status codes`.

I'm handling those return status values by `HttpContext.Current.Request["TransactionType"];`

Now, I need to do that in MVC, but my only confusion is how to submit form.

I've tried in MVC by using :

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("https://test2pay.ghl.com/IPGSG/Payment.aspx", null, FormMethod.Post)){
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg b-primary">Proceed to Payment</button>
        }
```

But, I'm getting redirected to this URL :

```
http://localhost:62414/Billing/https%3a/test2pay.ghl.com/IPGSG/Payment.aspx
```

Can anyone pls help me how I can submit a form using some data in MVC?

Comment: If the data is POST, it is not in the URL. It is the GET method that reads all of its data as parameters. You can always add a hidden field or use GET. NOTE: Do not put sensistive information in anything (HTML or URL) that you send to the client. If the data is sensitive, use some page in your application as  a proxy.

Comment: Don't use `Html.BeginForm()` just create a form tag manually

Comment: actually, I've kept the form tag manually, But I'm unable to pass data to the form.
I've tried with @Html.Hidden("ABC", @ViewData["ABCDATA"]).

But it is showing some web.config errors and with out the Hidden Value, the form is getting submitted

Comment: I need this data <%=eGHLPurchaseItems%> to be sent to the form

Comment: don't keep manual form tag, use razor instead

Comment: actually that was the tag in asp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either create html for tag or use

Your controller be like

```
ViewBag.CustId = "101";
ViewBag.Email = "cust@sss.sss";
```

And View

```
 @Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new {@action="https://test2pay.ghl.com/IPGSG/Payment.aspx"})
      {
         @Html.Hidden("id", @ViewBag.CustId);
         @Html.Hidden("email", @ViewBag.Email);
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg b-primary">Proceed to Payment</button>
      }
```

Since you are trying to redirect to external url, set `Action` and `Controller` to null.

Comment: your piece of code is also working fine.Do you know how to pass the data to it?
I'm getting data in ViewData

Comment: I guess your payment gateway provider must have provided you the format of data. you can pass it like @eGHLPurchaseItems

Comment: no...actually that was user defined variable.It can be of any name.
Actually in that, I'm passing some Input hidden tags like : string PymtMethodTemplate = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"PymtMethod\" value=\"ANY\">"; and soon. I'm finally preparing some input hidden fields into a string and then passing the data.

Comment: Which gateway you are using?

Comment: e-GHL, some malaysian gate way

Comment: Do you know how to pass data to this via webform, so that I can convert it to mvc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89797/discussion-between-realsteel-and-imadoddin-ibn-alauddin).

Comment: Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do an ajax post which has a few advantages over simply posting the form to the remote URL. Most importantly, it gives you the chance to gracefully handle any errors that might occur with the post.

```
<form action="https://test2pay.ghl.com/IPGSG/Payment.aspx" name="frmPost">

</form>

$("form").submit(function() {
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
        // here's where you check the response you got back from the post
        if (!data.IsOK)
        {
            // the post didn't succeed... handle error here or something
        }
        else
        {
            // the post succeeded so redirect back to this page
            window.location.href = '@Url.Content("~/")`;
        }
    });
});
```

There's a few things you'll need to consider before implementing this, however.

1. Does the URL you're posting to accept serialized JSON data?
2. What data does it return to let you know what happened with your post?

I can't help you with this first consideration, but for the 2nd, I highly recommend using [Fiddler Web Debugger](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to inspect the result of the post.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

In your model:

```
public string eGHLPurchaseItems { get; set; }
```

Do whatever you do to set eGHLPurchaseItems ...

In your View

```
   @using(Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" , @action="https://test2pay.ghl.com/IPGSG/Payment.aspx"}))
          {
             @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.eGHLPurchaseItems)
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg b-primary">Proceed to Payment</button>
          }

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myForm").submit();
    });
</script>
```